# object and array destructuring complications when passed to generator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, generator, destructuring

Trying to put some finishing touches on learning generators and destructuring, I made up an example and got it into my head I would pass the initial value 'i' of the generator's for iterable. Starting with an object, it wouldn't have worked unless I'd made several accidental discoveries.

Once it was working with an object for the setup parameters, I decided to throw an arrow function into the mix as well, but there is some funny behavior.

As the code shows now, the object works with both the initial value 'i' and the arrow function, but passing through the if statement at the top of genVal() the way it is now it still needs to see the destructuring statement again. I suspect this has something to do with scoping, but I would normally expect an error given two let statements referring to the same assignment, namely the passed param 'setup', optionally containing either the array or the object.

I've stripped back the initial value 'i' and the arrow function in another version, but there is some wonky stuff going on there, too.

Can you tell me what's going on here? And, if you're got it, what's a better approach to sending the multiplier 'valFactor' from the setup, rather than from the generator, as later I might want to turn this thing into a module and not revisit the code unless some refactoring is needed?

```js
function handler(val) {
  retVal = {}
  str = val.toString()
  // str = val
  dotIdx = str.indexOf(".")
  braceIdx = str.indexOf("(")
  retVal['head'] = str.slice(0, dotIdx)
  retVal['tail'] = str.slice(dotIdx + 1, braceIdx)
  return retVal
}

function calc(setup) {
  for (val of genVal(setup)) {
    // stringify and strip val using a handler
    let {
      head,
      tail
    } = handler(val)
    console.log(`Head: ${head} Tail: ${tail}`)
  }
}

function* genVal(setup) {
  // all passed will be objects so first distract for the object that is an array
  if (Array.isArray(setup)) {
    console.log("\n___________________________________________")
    console.log('array path')
    // changed from let to var re. stackoverflow comment
    // it's considered a bad solution as it breaks scope, and isn't the
    // accepted destructuring way, which would have a declaration
    // before the if...else block and retain these assignments, 
    // without var, let or const, and, for the object path, the statement wrapped in parentheses
    // see the answer below  
    var [i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor] = setup
  } else { // is going to be an object, for sure
    console.log("\n___________________________________________")
    console.log('object path')
    // changed from let to var re. stackoverflow comment
    var {
      i,
      iters,
      valTop,
      valBottom,
      valFactor
    } = setup
  }


  // // // arrSetup 'mode' 
  // w/ obj destructure below commented out
  // we traverse the array path, above
  // an error results without this duplication
  // and the arrow fn passed as valFactor does not 'work'
  //////////

  // let [i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor] = setup

  // // // objSetup 'mode' 
  // w/ arr destructure above commented out
  // we traverse the object path, above
  // an error results without this duplication
  //////////

  // let {
  //  i,
  //  iters,
  //  valTop,
  //  valBottom,
  //  valFactor
  // } = setup

  for (i; i <= iters; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    // console.log(valBottom)
    // console.log(valFactor)
    // newTail = valBottom + valFactor
    // console.log(newTail)

    if (i !== 1) {
      console.log(valTop + i)
      yield(valTop + i) / valFactor(valBottom)(i)
    } else {
      console.log(valTop)
      yield valTop / valBottom
    }
  }
}

// Two 'setup' types, one using arrSetup and the other using objSetup
// i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor
// arrSetup = [1, 2, 22, 7, (m) => m+.0101]
arrSetup = [1, 2, 22, 7, m => n => m+n]


objSetup = {
  "i": 1,
  "iters": 2,
  "valTop": 22,
  "valBottom": 7,
  "valFactor": m => n => m+n,
  // "valFactor": (i) => i + .9999,
}

calc(objSetup)
calc(arrSetup)
```

UPDATE:

<s>So, the scoping problem was easily fixed. Thanks.</s>

So, the scoping problem was a lot more interesting than I thought it would be, and the solution given really shows off a deeper understanding of Javascript grammar than I had before asking the question. The code here is pretty close to the original. Have a look at how Barmar keeps lexical scope to the function genVal(), but makes it possible to instance variables using destructuring from within the if...else block. Stranger things, but few IMHO.

On first post, the code's arrow function didn't work because the number of elements in the array was not consistent with assignment and destructuring. Doh! That has since been fixed. As it turns out, passing the function and then trying to use it does nothing, though I've only tried a few tricks of grammar to try to have valFactor work against valBottom in the generator's yield statement. Offline, I've sort of given up on passing a function and simply (for now) hard coded valFactor in the generator.

Now I'm after a technique which will allow a function (full or arrow) to be passed to the generator as a value of either or both the array or the object, and to get it to work in the yield expression with the present destructuring grammar intact (actually, Barmar's supplied grammar).

SOLVED:

Function currying solved my problem.

Instead of this:
`i => i * .9090`
This works, if the value of m and n are passed in context.
    `curried = m => n => m*n`
And the call:
    `curried(varforM)(varforN)`

Note: Omitting one of the variables in the call results in one of the arrow functions as the return value.

Comment: There's no error for multiple `let` bindings because they're all local to their enclosing blocks. So the scopes of those variables are just the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: Why do you keep trying to edit my answer?

Comment: If it doesn't work, post a comment below it explaining the problem. If you think there's a better way, post your own answer.

Comment: You're not calling the arrow function. It needs to be `+ valFactor(something)`

Comment: Did you intend for the code not to run, as that's how I found it. That might have been ok, but it also didn't seem to reveal much of use about how destructuring works in context...

Comment: I didn't get any error messages from the destructuring assignments. I don't really understand what your code is trying to do, I thought that was the only issue.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple `var` declarations for the same variables in a function. It doesn't get an error, though. The second set are just treated as assignments.

Comment: I apologize. The first time I ran it right after you posted, it errored out. Now it works, but I don't see what's different. Very interesting approach. Very arcane to remove the explicit literal from the let declaration at the top of genVal() and, I guess, what, 'escape' the object using function notation? Wow. Couldn't have guessed...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by function notation. The parentheses are just required to disambiguate it, because curly braces are used for multiple things in JS.

Comment: When they added destructuring to the language, they had to shoehorn it into an existing grammar that already had a meaning for a statement beginning with curly braces. It's similar to the reason why you need to put an IIFE in parentheses, because a statement beginning with `function` is expected to be a definition.

Comment: I was actually getting errors until I added them, I had to do a google search to find the trick.

Comment: I was able to get your changes to run in the node debugger in vscode putting the terminator on only the console.log(); statements before each of the destructuring assignments within the if statement. That seems odd. Maybe that's also part of the shoehorn you're talking about. The parenthetical explanation still hasn't sunk in for me after early days of such constructions making fun of my intelligence... Shouldn't be too difficult to remember now, though.

Comment: It's very simple. If a statement begins with `{`, it's the beginning of a block of lines, like the body of a function or the body of an `if` statement. So you can't start a destructuring assignment with `{`, because it will try to parse the rest of it as a code block, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a destructuring `let` to initialize variables from either an object or array. Since the `let` statements are inside `if` and `else` blocks, the scopes will just be those blocks, not the enclosing function.

What you can do is declare the variables first, then use destructuring assignments in the `if` and `else`.

Note that a destructuring assignment to an object has to be enclosed in parentheses, because if a statement begins with `{` it's assumed to be the beginning of a block, not an object.

```js
function handler(val) {
  retVal = {};
  str = val.toString();
  // str = val
  dotIdx = str.indexOf(".");
  braceIdx = str.indexOf("(");
  retVal['head'] = str.slice(0, dotIdx);
  retVal['tail'] = str.slice(dotIdx + 1, braceIdx);
  return retVal;
}

function calc(setup) {
  for (val of genVal(setup)) {
    // stringify and strip val using a handler
    let {
      head,
      tail
    } = handler(val);
    console.log(`Head: ${head} Tail: ${tail}`);
  }
}

function* genVal(setup) {
  let i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor;
  // all passed will be objects so first distract for the object that is an array
  if (Array.isArray(setup)) {
    console.log("\n___________________________________________");
    console.log('array path');
    [i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor] = setup;
  } else { // is going to be an object, for sure
    console.log("\n___________________________________________");
    console.log('object path');
    ({i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor} = setup);
  }

  for (i; i <= iters; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(valBottom);
    console.log(valFactor);
    newTail = valBottom + valFactor;
    console.log(newTail);

    if (i !== 1) {
      console.log(valTop + i);
      yield(valTop + i) / valBottom + valFactor;
    } else {
      console.log(valTop);
      yield valTop / valBottom;
    }
  }
}

// Two 'setup' types, one using arrSetup and the other using objSetup
// i, iters, valTop, valBottom, valFactor
arrSetup = [1, 2, 3, (i) => i * .0101];

objSetup = {
  "i": 1,
  "iters": 2,
  "valTop": 22,
  "valBottom": 7,
  "valFactor": (i) => i * .0101,
};

calc(objSetup);
calc(arrSetup);
```